# week calculation by Month

Tags: sql-server-2005

How can I get the week no by month where week starts from Monday by using select statement?

For an example '2013-01-06' = Sunday.

This should be fall under week 1.

Please assis.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
select DATEPART( wk, '2-21-2013') -DATEPART( wk, '2-1-2013')+1  FROM table;
```

This works in the way add the date in the first part deduct it with the 1st of that month +1

Edit

Assuming your separate month, day, year value are in varchar

```
Select CAST(year + '-' + month + '-' + date AS DATETIME) - 
CAST(year + '-' + month + '-01' AS DATETIME) + 1 From table
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/189a3/1157)

Comment: Thanks for posting.. But I can't do this as I have to calculate on a date field. I have used : date part(day,date diff(day,0,calendar_date)/7 * 7) /7 +1

Comment: I believe that `2013-01-06` will be displayed as second week.

Comment: @IvanG yes It considers sunday as first day of week. To make it monday have to set datefirst 1

Comment: Yes, I know. The OP specified that 2013-01-06 should fall under first week.

Comment: @IvanG Tks for drawing my attention.

Comment: Thanks!! But I have to use on fields instead of specific dates.  
Suppose my table has calendar date, calendar month, calendar year. Here I have to calculate week no by month. Like for jan 1,2,3,4,5, for feb 1,2,3,4 like wise.

Comment: I am using :
CEILING(CAST(date part(dd,GET DATE()) AS numeric (38,8)) / 7)
It's giving me right result if I am using a single date.. If I am using a period like from 2012-01-01 to 2013-06-30.. Then for 1st Jan it is giving me 5th week and 2nd week of January is giving me as week 1. Please assist.